# VUE3 pass data between files

Tags: vue.js, components, vue-component, vuejs3, pass-data

In **Home.vue** I get data from **db.json** and store it into **jobs: []** array.

```js
export default {
  name: 'Home',
  data() {
    return {
      jobs: [],
    }
  },
  components: {
    
  },
  mounted() {
    fetch("http://localhost:3000/jobs")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => this.jobs = data)
      .catch(err => console.log(err.message))
  }
}
```

Also in **Home.vue** I show this data, but only in a short list with:

```js
v-for="job in jobs.slice(0, 5)"
```

In **AllJobs.vue** I want to show the full data from **db.json** and in **AddJob.vue** I will make a form to be able to add data to ***db.json***.

In **App.vue** I have the router-links:

```html
<template>
  <div class="container">
      <div class="navigation">
        <h1 class="title">{{ $route.name }}</h1>
        <nav>
          <router-link :to="{ name: 'Latest open positions' }">Home</router-link>
          <router-link :to="{ name: 'All open positions' }">Jobs</router-link>
          <router-link :to="{ name: 'Add a new job' }">Dashboard</router-link>
        </nav>
      </div>
    <router-view/>
  </div>
</template>
```

How I pass data from **Home.vue** into **AllJobs.vue**?

Should I get another fetch method into **AllJobs.vue** to get data?

Should I get data into **App.vue** and then pass it into files that I need?

What is the best approach?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to handling API requests and sharing data between components, what you need is some state management solution like [pinia](https://pinia.vuejs.org/).

You can fetch and save your data in a store and then use it in any component:

jobs.js

```
export const useJobsStore = defineStore('jobs', {
  state: () => ({ jobs: [] }),
  actions: {
    fetchJobs() {
      fetch("http://localhost:3000/jobs")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => this.jobs = data)
        .catch(err => console.log(err.message))
    },
  },
})
```

App.vue

```
import { mapActions } from 'pinia
import { useJobsStore } from './jobs.js'

export default {
  methods: {
    ...mapActions(useJobsStore, ['fetchJobs'])
  },

  mounted() {
    this.fetchJobs()
  }
}
```

Home.vue and AllJobs.vue

```
import { mapState } from 'pinia'
import { useJobsStore } from './jobs.js'

export default {
  computed: {
    // this makes this.jobs available in script and template
    ...mapState(useJobsStore, ['jobs'])
  }
}
```

One thing which is debatable is where to call `fetchJobs` action

1. In App.vue or main.js - this will fetch data as soon as you open the app, but can be unnecessary if the page you visit doesn't even use the data.
2. In each page that uses the data - solves the previous problem, but fetches the same data multiple times.
3. In each page that uses the data (with caching) - you can modify `fetchJobs` to make a request only if the data haven't been fetched already. This way the app will fetch the data as soon as you visit some page which uses it. And if you visit another page, it will use the cached value instead of making a request

There isn't a singe best approach, which one to pick depends on your needs

Comment: I used your code and it says that "defineStore" is not defined.

Comment: First, you need to add pinia to your project. You can read how to do this here https://pinia.vuejs.org/getting-started.html